# Regarding vs2012 javascript Intellisense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, javascript-intellisense

I have custom javascript code in A.js file,to have intellisense associated with it,I have A.intellise
nse.js file in the same folder as A.js.

Content of A.js:

```
 var test = (typeof test === "undefined") || !test ? {} : test;


 test= (function () {
              return {
                 Version: "1.0.0"
           };
     }());
```

Content of A.intellisense.js

```
intellisense.annotate(window, {
"test": function () {
    /// <signature>
    ///   <summary>The Version of the test JavaScript Lbrary</summary>
    /// </signature>
   }
 });
```

Since test is defined at window level,I can use test function in B.js file without referring to A.js in it.
When I type test(),I do not get any intellisense, Where I am going wrong.

P.S : Even I have _reference.js file and A.js is referred in it.

Answer (score 1):

You're close to the right solution - the problem is that in your example source you're defining test as a global variable, not a global function. In your A.intellisense.js file you're annotating it as a function, but since it isn't a function you won't see any comments.

Here are a couple solutions to help you out, depending on your intent.

**If test is supposed to be a global variable**

You can annotate test as a variable by using:

```
intellisense.annotate(window, {
    // This is a comment about "test"
    "test": undefined
});
```

**If test is supposed to be a function**

Then you can define test as function, and your annotation should work:

```
function test() {
    return {
        "Version": "1.0.0"
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!
- Jordan (Microsoft Visual Studio PM - JavaScript tools)